# jQuery: Make a button emulate another button

Tags: jquery

How is it possible to make 'Delete' (I will rename it 'Replace') button emulate Browse button?
I mean when hitting 'Delete' to actually browse for another file?

[image]

Comment: `Browse` is added by the browser, so ythat I know of you can't control what it says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JQuery, see the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AF2c5/1 for a working example:

The HTML markup:

```
<input type="file" id="fileButton" />
<button id="myButton">Delete</button>
```

And the javascript:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#fileButton').click();
});
```

You can also remove the original file input and only browse with a custom button: http://jsfiddle.net/AF2c5/2/:

```
<input type="file" id="fileButton" style="display: none" />
```

Be aware that hiding the input can break in certain (mobile) browsers. Then you are better off with positioning the original input off screen instead of hiding it, see http://jsfiddle.net/AF2c5/3/:

```
<input type="file" id="fileButton" style="position: absolute;  top: -50%; left: -50%" />
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the "delete"-button has the same functionality and target as the "Browse"-Button, I would trigger on the target an click event.

Comment: Something like this as function on click on _your_ button: $('#myFileSelect').click();

Answer (score 1):

You can always use onclick javascript event on the second button.

for example if you have your file input tag, named 'file1', and the button inside a form, named 'form1', then on click of the 2nd button trigger click() on the 'file1' input.

Something like:

```
<form name="form1">
   <input name="file1" type=file />
   <button type="button" onclick="document.form1.file1.click()">replace</button>
</form>
```